# Using http proxy server? objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, nsurlconnection

How to use a proxy server with 'NSURLConnection'?

I want to use a proxy server when open a url connection with objective-c.

But I don't want to use any other frameworks in my project.

Can anyone tell how to accomplish this?

Comment: accordingly to the matt comment [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/736) it seems not to be possible using only `NSURLConnection`

Comment: So,is there any other solution?It's better not to use other frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to use an external framework

Comment: Thank you , I will have a try.